# Django Rest Swagger with APIView

Tags: django, rest, serialization, django-rest-framework, swagger

I'm trying to integrate Swagger to my Django Rest Framework API. I installed the relevant package and followed the quickstart guide from the Github page. I'm having some problems though. Swagger only shows the doc-comment of the view.

Basically I have one APIView which interprets given url (because it can has n-amount of "tokens" eg. "/first/second/" or "/a/b/c/d/e/f/g") makes a a db-query and selects a correct serializer to return the data depending on the request type and the resource at the end of the url.

If I have understood Swagger's workings correctly, it uses serializer to get the example json input and other relevant data to be shown in the ui. Is there any way to explicitly tell it the serializer it should use?

Finally here is an example of my APIView's GET-code to show the serializer usage. As you can see there is two different serializers used:

```
isValid = self.isValidUrl(request.path)
    if not isValid:
        return Response("Error: The url is empty.")

    url = self.trimTheUrl(request.path)
    print url

    try:
        target = models.APINode.objects.get(uniquePath=url)
        perm = IsOwner()
        perm.has_object_permission(request, self, target)
        #check is the APINode collection or item:
        if target.objectType == "item":
            #return JSON data of the materialItem:
            serializer = ProductSerializer(target.materialItem)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            #find objects in this collection
            children = models.APINode.objects.filter(parentPath=target.uniquePath)
            serializer = APINodeSerializer(children, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)

    except models.APINode.DoesNotExist:
        return Response("404: No such collection or materialItem.")
```

For whatever it's worth the API represents a collection & resource structure much like a file system with n-deep paths.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to do this with a tag called serializer. An example would be `serializer: UserDocSerializer`. It you be something like:

```
"""
Your View
---
... All about parameters and types ...
serializer: UserDocSerializer
...
```

The problem that I got is that it always try to make me the import of the seriallizer from the views, so I had to declare this in the views.py like:

```
class UserDocSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('username', 'image')
```

With this you just get the fields that you want to show to